# Apache serverSignature

Tags: apache

I am using xampp with Apache/2.4.2.
I am trying to hide serverSignature.
That is what i am writing in my httpd.conf file.

serverSignature Off
serverTokens Major

I have tried serverSignature and serverTokens one by one and also tried them together.
But the result is still the same i.e
"Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4 Server at localhost Port 80"
What is wrong with what im doing?
I restarted the apache each time i changed the httpd.conf file.
I am new to Apache.
Please help me with this guys.
Also can you suggest me a resourse where i acn learn Apache,other than apache's?
Thanks

Comment: i downloaded apache 2.2.21 serverSignature worked on it the way i wanted it to.
But i dont know why it is not working for xampp

Answer (score 1):

I just now found the solution to my serverSignature problem, i was having with exampp.
i was messing around with its configuration files while i saw httpd-default.conf file in /xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf.
there i saw both above directives, i changed there arguments and apache worked the way i wanted it to.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For XAMPP, go to `/xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf`, and edit it to set the options `serverSignature=Off` and `serverTokens=Prod`.